# Using symbols in JSX and React Native

Tags: react-native, jsx

I would like to use [this symbol](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/arrows/heavy-round-tipped-right-arrow/) in my React Native project.

I tried using the Unicode encoding like this:

```
    var arrow = "U+0279C";
```

And in the JSX:

```
   <Text>
      {arrow}
   </Text>
```

However, this just displays the encoding literally: `U+0279C`.

So any idea how can I use a symbol in JSX?

Comment: That returns `ɹC`, where `ɹ` is the character for `U+0279`. http://graphemica.com/%C9%B9

Comment: right, try: "\u279C"

Comment: That works! How come this encoding works and the other doesn't?

Comment: not sure, but http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch24.html

Answer (score 14):

You should use the HTML code for the symbol.

```
<Text>
    &#10140;
</Text>
```

As described in notes below.. (important, quotes don't seem to work)...

> Just to clarify: `<Text>&#10140;</Text>` will work, but `<Text>{ '&#10140;' }</Text>` will not.

Comment: Just to clarify: `<Text>&#10140;</Text>` will work, but `<Text>{ '&#10140;' }</Text>` will not.

Answer (score 4):

Use this functions for symbols in this format: **& # 1 7 4 ;**

```
/**
 * replaces /$#d\+/ symbol with actual symbols in the given string
 * 
 * Returns given string with symbol code replaced with actual symbol
 * 
 * @param {string} name 
 */
export function convertSymbolsFromCode(name = '') {
  let final = null;
  if (name) {
    const val = name.match(/&#\d+;/) ? name.match(/&#\d+;/)[0] : false; // need to check whether it is an actual symbol code
    if (val) {
      const num = val.match(/\d+;/) ? val.match(/\d+;/)[0] : false; // if symbol, then get numeric code
      if (num) {
        final = num.replace(/;/g, '');
      }
    }
    if (final) {
      name = name.replace(/&#\d+;/g, String.fromCharCode(final));
    }
  }
  return name;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
<Text>
   {convertSymbolsFromCode(this.state.unicode)}
 </Text>
```

Answer (score 2):

The provided answer did not work for me, since I was dynamically retrieving unicode hex codes from an API. I had to pass them as JavaScript into the react-native jsx code.

The following answer worked for me:
[Concatenate unicode and variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54507964)

I used `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(unicode, 16))` and it worked.

Example:

```
const unicode = unicodeHexValueFromApi //This value equals "05D2"

return(<Text>{String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(unicode, 16))}</Text>)
```

Answer (score -3):

```html
<Text>{"Any character"}</Text>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This is not as helpful as providing a real example of answering the OP's question or using an arrow-like symbol instead of `"Any character"`.