# Concatenate unicode and variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm newbie in React and I have some issue to display dynamic unicode value ?

```
{'\u{1F680}'} become {'\u{MyVar}'}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) will get you the character from its numeric code point, and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will get you the number from a hex string.

Your conversion will look like the following : `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(MyVariable, 16))`

Working example :

```js
const App = ({ unicode }) => <p> 3, 2, 1, GO ! {String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(unicode, 16))}</p>

ReactDOM.render(<App unicode='1F680'/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Comment: THA BEST! Thank you very much! Been hours browsing.

Comment: Worked like a gem!✅