# React Native Custom Font HTML Entity

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'm using custom font (from Flaticon) which is already working to show the custom font in my React Native app using:

```
<Text style={styles.flaticonText}>&#xf169;</Text> // working
```

or

```
<Text style={styles.flaticonText}>{"\uf169"}</Text> // working
```

And I'm trying to make it dynamic from DB, so I try to use:

```
<Text style={styles.flaticonText}>{val.icon_code}</Text> // not working
```

but it shows string &#xf169; on the screen instead. I have tried changing `icon_code` value in database to '\f169' but no luck, it shows string 169 not an icon.

Comment: What kind of database do you use? Do you use any encoding?

Comment: @Rene MySQL, utf8 (general_ci)

Comment: can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! It is [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint). So I updated all `icon_code` in my database to like: 'f169' and render with this:

```
<Text style={styles.flaticonText}>{String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(val.icon_code, 16))}</Text>
```

Thanks for this thread: [Concatenate unicode and variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507964/concatenate-unicode-and-variable). Second argument of `parseInt` is 16 for hexadecimal ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)).